# Flask WTForm data return csrf_token when try to access all data

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am using Flask WTForm, and try to get the data from flask flask WTForm using `form.data`, but that return `csrf_token` as one of the field.

My File structure is as below

```
$ tree .
.
└── testing_app
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── forms.py
    ├── templates
    │   ├── index.html
    │   └── submit.html
    └── views.py
```

**forms.py**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('name', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

**views.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect

from testing_app import forms

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = b'randomkey'

@app.route('/submit', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def submit():
    form = forms.MyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        app.logger.debug(form.data)
        return redirect('/')
    return render_template('submit.html', form=form)

@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    this is index page
</html>
```

**submit.html**

```
<form method="POST" action="/submit">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.name.label }} {{ form.name(size=20) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

I ran it using

```
export FLASK_APP=testing_app/views.py
export FLASK_DEBUG=1
flask run

 * Serving Flask app "testing_app.views"
 * Forcing debug mode on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 245-821-651
```

When I go to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/submit` and click on `ok` with name as `test`, it redirects to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` and log the data as

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG in views [/Users/nile2691/my_tests/testing_app/views.py:13]:
{'csrf_token': 'TOKEN', 'name': 'test'}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Oct/2018 15:03:34] "POST /submit HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Oct/2018 15:03:34] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Is there any way to get the `data` without `csrf_token`?

I know, I can access `form.name`, but where I have to try, it has `15` fields, and I am trying to avoid to do for each field.

I can also do like

```
for key, value in form.data.items():
    if key == 'csrf_token`:
        continue
    # process with other data
```

but if we add `SubmitField` in `Form`, `form.data` will return that too.

I am looking for flask way, to get only `string` or `selection` field from form.

Comment: Well, `csrf_token` is just a normal section, there is no different between this one and the others except for hidden. Why `WTForm` should treat it as special?

Comment: is there any way to get `non hidden` fields ?

Comment: Hidden is a html property. The incoming data does even have that difference. It's just impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form object has a _fields property which contains all of the fields in the form. If you iterate through this you will have access to the field name, data and type and you can build your own data dict containing only the field types you want. The following should work.

```
data = {field.name: field.data for field in form._fields.values() if type(field) in (StringField, SelectField)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You access all your data if they are valid in *Flask-WTF* as

```
form.name_of_input_field.data
```

In your example that is:

```
form = forms.MyForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    app.logger.debug(form.name.data) # not form.data
    return redirect('/')
return render_template('submit.html', form=form)
```

Take a look at my example:
[create article form](https://github.com/PinkFrojd/material_aukcije_online/blob/master/forms/article_form.py)
[permalink to creating article](https://github.com/PinkFrojd/material_aukcije_online/blob/5be5ebb17b40613a7a5ace698354f820151d07ac/controllers/create_article_controller.py#L48)